# While using Offline Files users cannot rename files when changing case only

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-8.1, offline-files

I recently setup some new computers (running Win8.1) for the staff here. These machines use folder redirection (as we always have) with Offline Files sync. I have not traditionally used Offline Files but I've turned it on to give a bit of extra resiliency and performance while working with their files.

Today it was brought to my attention by someone that they cannot rename a file if they change the letter case only. When they do this they are shown a popup that says they need to get permission from their selves to perform the action. Their choices are Try Again and  Cancel.

For example, the following will fail:

```
filename.txt --> FILENAME.txt
```

But the following will succeed:

```
filename.txt --> xFILENAME.txt --> FILENAME.txt
```

My files are being redirected to the same fileshare* by the same group policy but I am not using Offline Files and I do not experience this problem.

I've checked with another user that is setup like the original and they also experience this problem.

If this is a known bug my I have not been able to find an answer.

```
* The fileshare is running on Windows Server 2012 with deduplication enabled on the volume.
```

Comment: FWIW, I see the same behavior on an off-line file.

Comment: What do you mean off-line file? A normal file that is not redirected and not synced locally by Offline Files?

Comment: @idon'twearsuits  Yes, that's what he means.  This is a problem with Windows going back to the FAT-filesystem days, and I *assume* it is still an issue because of how Windows handles FAT-compatibility.  Not related to offline-files or folder-redirection.  I recall having some documentation from a support KB about this somewhere... I'll try to dig it up.

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork Interesting... I don't think I've ever seen this before in all my years doing this.

Comment: Also happens with Windows 7 Pro x64 clients with Server 2008 R2 Standard x64 servers. GPO has Documents folder redirected to be on the server and a local offline cached copy is on the client machine which does bidirectional sync with the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Vista and Windows 7 this is a known 'feature' according to the [Microsoft KB953945](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953945), with the only 'resolution' is to work around the problem by temporarily renaming the file to something else first.

From the above article the resolution is

> To work around this issue, rename the file to another name, and then rename back with the changed letter case.
>
> For example, rename TEXT.txt to word.txt, and then rename word.txt to text.txt.

Perhaps with Windows 8, 8.1, 2012, 2012R2 this 'feature' has been included in these newer releases too.